# Trouble sending Rails script output to Foreman console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, ruby-on-rails-4, foreman

**Problem:**

I am using the popular Foreman gem to run a number of rails scripts/daemons. I'm encountering a problem with getting the output of one of my scripts to display in the foreman console.

I'm using a ruby Logger instance to handle all of the logging in the script and I'm initializing the logger to output to `STDOUT` like so:

```
logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

None of the output is appearing in Foreman. Why is this?

**Other tidbits:**

I have the following `require` at the top of my script. `puts [message]` outputs to the foreman console when run before this `require`, but no output occurs if run after. The `p` command works in either instance.

```
require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'environment'))
```

If I initialize the logger to `STDERR` instead, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in the foreman wiki on github:

> If you are not seeing any output from your program, there is a likely
>   chance that it is buffering stdout. Many languages such as Ruby and
>   Python buffer stdout by default. To disable this behavior, add this code as early as possible in your program:
>
> $stdout.sync = true

source: https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/wiki/Missing-Output